# 'No module named happybase' when running from PIG

Tags: python, hbase, apache-pig, jython, happybase

I have a Python UDF which is connecting to HBase using Happybase. If I run the code from Python 2.7 it works perfectly.

However when I call the Python UDF from Pig 0.15.0 I am getting the following error:

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1121: Python Error. Traceback (most recent call last): import happybase ImportError: No module named happybase

In my Pig script I am registering my Python script (pigtest.py) like this:

```
REGISTER 'pigtest.py' using jython as myfuncs;
```

I tried to set the Happybase path in my Python script as follows but that didn't make a difference:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/happybase')
import happybase
```

I also tried adding "*/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/happybase*" to the JYTHON_PATH in the .bashrc file (I'm on Ubuntu) but same error comes up.

It seems to me like I need to set the Happybase path somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: When you register the UDF, I believe the path it looks at is HDFS. So if happybase is on your local filesystem, it won't work the way you have set it up. That also explains why pigtest.py works on its own - move it to another machine without happybase, and it won't work again

Comment: I see, so is there a way to get Happybase to work in this scenario? Also my 'pigtest.py' is on the local filesystem (same folder as the Pig script) and not in HDFS but it does find it, or is that different?

Comment: Since you do `REGISTER 'pigtest.py'`, that will look for files locally, but uploads it to HDFS behind the scenes. You could implicitly put `pigtest.py` on HDFS, then do something like `REGISTER 'hdfs:///tmp/pigtest.py'`. As for the Happybase issue, I'd have to look into it further since I haven't used a Python UDF before.

Comment: I found that I get the same error if I try to import happybase from Jython (outside of PIG). I think there must be an environment variable or something where I need to specify the path to the Happybase files. Any idea on what you need to do to import modules when using Jython? I have Jython 2.5.3 installed.

Comment: Not sure, never actually used Jython. Is there a particular reason you're using Jython over python?

Comment: Because Pig executes Python UDFs in Jython, and I don't think you can change that (although I'm pretty new to this whole Hbase/Pig thing!)

Comment: Alright, I guess a better question is why do you need a UDF? I think pig has an hbase connector. I agree using a UDF allows use of a familiar library, but I imagine you're just trying to read/store some values

Comment: Yes I was able to read from HBase directly from Pig, but at this stage it's mainly evaluation of the possibilities. In the end what I want to achieve is to read data from HDFS, and for each event get some corresponding data from HBase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the help of the Jython user mailing list. You need to specify the parent directory of the Happybase folder, not the path to the Happybase dir itself like I was doing, by doing one of the following:

Append the location to the sys.path in the Python script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
import happybase
```

**OR**

Add the location as an environment variable to JYTHONPATH (not JYTHON_PATH!):

```
export JYTHONPATH = $JYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```